# Man throws himself into frozen river to die, how long can he survive?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I have character that has been on a path of destruction for a bit too long and decides to finish it all

**He can't swim. River's temperate is about -5c. And it is a deep river**

So. after all the story elements deciding to kill himself and finding his sword stuck in its scabbard he looks at the lovely frozen river and decides to take a refreshing bath and... also die in pain as he is done.

Now. This is what I want to be done. I want him to throw himself into the river and drift down river then to be rescued by the Emperor's soldiers as a couple is relieving themselves by the river.
They find a body stuck to a tree by the river and think to fish it out and at least give him a burial.

Turns out he is alive!
This will lead him to find purpose in the emperor's service and start his path of redemption.

Now I want him to survive the maximum amount of time in the river which will be convey with the passage of time. It should be something rare but **not** magical, merely a 1/1000 type of events.

**So. What is the maximum amount of time he can spend in the river and still be alive?**

If the frame is broken then what do I need to change? Like do I need to make the river shallow or increase the temperature or what?

Comment: In a river at -5 Celsius nobody would drown because it would be totally frozen solid at that temperature

Comment: It would depend of his clothing, and when he last ate. He would be lying ON TOP of a frozen sheet of ice, so exposure to the elements and/or starvation are his greatest threats. He might get arrested by the park police though.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica, err not really, flowing and or salt water wont freeze as easily

Comment: This would be better at home in Medical Sciences.SE

Comment: @Topcode Fresh water is liquid if it's over 0 degrees C (unless it's under 100 mPA of pressure) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point#/media/File:Phase_diagram_of_water.svg

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question asks for information that is well researched and available from the web -- https://www.ussartf.org/cold_water_survival.htm

Comment: @EDL,
One of the reasons I asked this hear is people offer story oriented answers.
For example "MarvinKitfox" offered an interesting story about someone surviving for 80 minutes.
Such anecdotes allows a writer to work within established scientific facts and reality. So. Like I said what is the 1/1000 is and what is the norm...etc
"Willk" again offers a helpful answer.
I get your point and it's fine.
But sometimes the mindset of worldbuilders in answering can provide more help than mere dry academic facts.
Thanks for the input thought.

Comment: @Seallussus "One of the reasons I asked this here is for people to offer story-oriented answers." Remember one of our VTC reasons is "too story-based." You literally asked for a purpose that's off-topic here.

Comment: @JBH,
let me rephrase that. "Answers that come from people who has in their mind how research for stories are made thus when they encounter a problem they have an overall idea of how to approach the subject in the larger context of worldbuilding"
This removes the mere facts academic approach or simply: what is the scientific method to create penicillin in 1950.
Ultimately every single 1+1=? question can be answered with: go do scientific research, right?
There are great people here but others donwvote a question without reading half of it and others want you to be Hemingway in comments.

Comment: @JBH, 
And I'm not saying it is a bad place or that people should change nor saying I have a ratio of X to X.
Merely saying that sometimes it's too difficult to communicate. Best example is this comment. I'm trying to talk like I'm in an academic debate or something and trying to cover all bases and it is not a human way to communicate.
Yes I admitted several times before that I was wrong and learned from other points. I'm willing to go so again.
But if I need to cover all bases before talking with others then honestly are they here to help or what?
Probably grammar errors too.

Comment: What's your native language, Seallussus?

Comment: @JBH,
That would be Arabic.

Comment: Rats. I was hoping it was a language I was familiar with - it could have helped bridge the gap. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Ignoring the -5C... This is a river, thus freshwater.
People are using the river to relieve themselves, so not very frozen over.
Assume little ice, 0 to 1 C water

For a healthy male adult human wearing winter clothing (long sleeves and pants) which will trap a measure of water around the body rather than direct exposure to the river:

- Death from hypothermia in about [45 minutes](http://www.seagrant.umn.edu/coastal_communities/hypothermia). (yes, that slow)
- possible death from direct cold incapacitation in about 20 minutes. At this point voluntary muscle movement is disabled. Drowning is very likely.
- but assuming he floats face-up and gets rescued by someone: 45 minutes if fully immersed. Historically one person survived this for 80 minutes: [Anna Bågenholm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_B%C3%A5genholm)
- If floating on a plank or tree or something, with 50% of the body supported out of the water: about 3 hours.

This only determines whether the person is *alive* when fished out of the water. Recovery from such acute hypothermia is medically difficult and requires specialized treatment.

Comment: thats quite a while

Comment: [Edit] your answer to [refer to this post and chart](http://www.seagrant.umn.edu/coastal_communities/hypothermia), it will give your answer more credibility.

Comment: @JBH,
That chart is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[“Nobody is dead until warm and dead”: Prolonged resuscitation is warranted in arrested hypothermic victims also in remote areas – A retrospective study from northern Norway](https://www.resuscitationjournal.com/article/S0300-9572(14)00524-3/fulltext)

If you cool down quick, you can survive being dead for several hours.

> ...nine out of 24 (37.5%) survived hypothermic cardiac arrest from
> 1999 to 2013. The lowest measured core temperature among survivors was
> 13.7 °C; the longest time from cardiac arrest to return of spontaneous circulation was 6 h and 52 min. The only predictor of survival
> identified was lower blood potassium concentration in the nine
> survivors compared with the non-survivors. Submersion was not
> associated with reduced survival.

I find it interesting that submersion is not associated with reduced survival.  Cold water definitely cools you faster and as regards not being permanently dead, cooler is better.  I wonder if submersion is not associated with worse outcomes because of the [diving reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_reflex) which is an involuntary cessation of breathing on being suddenly immersed in cold water.

In any case, 6 hours dead is a good long time and long enough for your story.  They can wrap the guy up and bring him back.  Maybe someone knows about the trick and warms him up in a bath, or maybe they leave him in a stable and it is warm in there and he just comes stumbling out.  I think he might lose his nose and ears to frostbite but that will make him more interesting.